# Is it possible to declare Queue as: Queue<Integer,Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer,Integer>() in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

If it is, how do we retrieve the values while polling?

```
?=q.poll();
```

Comment: No, it is not possible (unless you are talking about some different Queue, not from `java.util` package). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Queue can only have one type.

Comment: @Pshemo  Queue would be the perfect data structure for my task in terms of accessing and deleting, however I wanted to store x and y coordinates. I'm unsure how I can modify it?

Comment: You could create your own `Pair<X,Y>` class which could store x and y pairs and put such pairs into your `Queue<Pair<X,Y>>`. So technically your queue will store only one type `Pair` but that type itself can store two other types.

Comment: @Pshemo that makes sense. Thanks.